# How can I make the sidebar mobile responsive with bootstrap?

Tags: html, css

I have this sidebar created with bootstrap, and I just need it to be mobile responsive. How can I do that?

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="sidebar col-lg-2 col-md-3">
            <h2>Wiki</h2>
            <form action="/">
                <input class="search" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search Encyclopedia">
            </form>
            <div>
                <a href="{% url 'index' %}">Home</a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="{% url 'newpage' %}">Create New Page</a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="{% url 'random' %}">Random Page</a>
            </div>
            {% block nav %}
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
        <div class="main col-lg-10 col-md-9">
            {% block body %}
            {% endblock %}
        </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: hi, @alejandro welcome to SO. the first place to check in learning bootstrap is following the official documentation. check https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/ and https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/ hope it will help you not only in this case but also when you building the rest of your website.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Wiki</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'index' %}">Home</a>
      </li>
      
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'newpage' %}">Create New Page</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'random' %}">Random Page</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you to design responsive side bar as per screen size

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Sidebar Responsive Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My Logo</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
      </li>    
    </ul>
  </div>  
</nav>
<br>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Responsive Navbar</h3>
  <p>This is just a demo content.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```